# Nuclear Dawn Giveaway

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

> **Update:** We are at 15 people!  **psychonic says:** I'm still awaiting contact from a few of them. If you still have interest, feel free to reply, although I cannot guarantee you a key. Regardless, everyone that received one also received three guest passes and I hear that the game is going on sale on Steam soon (...as in, next week)

> The short version:  Want a free copy of Nuclear Dawn?  You need **300 rep** on Gaming, be in the [Nuclear Dawn steam group](http://steamcommunity.com/games/nucleardawn), be willing to play the game, and be willing to **ask or answer 6 questions in the next 2 weeks.**  Read on for details...

[Nuclear Dawn](http://www.nucleardawnthegame.com/) is a hybrid FPS/RTS game published by [Interwave Studios](http://www.interwavestudios.com/).  A good friend of mine works there, and he is looking to get the word out about the game and celebrate their most recent update.  I, of course, suggested we **give away free games** to the good people of the Gaming.SE community.

Here's what you've got to do:

- Review the [system requirements](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17710/) to make sure you can run the game.
- Have **300 rep** on Gaming.SE!  Gain reputation by contributing good questions and answers to the site.
- Join the **[Nuclear Dawn](http://steamcommunity.com/games/nucleardawn) group** on Steam.
- **Post an answer to this question (this one that you are reading right now), and include your Steam profile link.**  You'll get a friend invite from [**psychonic**](http://steamcommunity.com/id/psychonic) who will hook you up with your free copy.
- **Play the game!**  Get out there and enjoy it.  If you like it, tell your friends :)
- Post **at least 6 things in the next 2 weeks** with the [nuclear-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-dawn) tag - these can be questions OR answers.  Stuff that's garbage (closed or negative score) does not count :)

Now the fine print:

Copies are limited!  We have around 15 to give out, and they will be given out first-come first-serve.  This giveaway ends on **April 12th, 2012, or when all copies have been given away.**

Although I have permission from the SE team to do this, this is not an official SE event.  There's no tie between this and the "official" gaming grant(s) or other site promotions/contests, so your participation in this event will not affect any further SE-sponsored activities.  However, I reserve the right to disqualify people from future "cool things" that I may get access to in the future if you participate in bad faith.

Comment: Are you going to count posts that end up negatively voted or closed?

Comment: And also, this is awesome! I know nothing about Nuclear Dawn, but I'll definitely be checking it out now.

Comment: @AnnaLear, I added that as a caveat.  The only threat I can make is to glare at you sternly should you fail, but I can assure you the glaring is going to be *intense.*

Comment: Thanks for the help getting this going, agent86!

Comment: Nuclear Dawn is a bunch of fun.  If anyone wants to get a game together some night, ping me in chat with your Steam name and I'll add you

Comment: this is just a sneaky way of collecting steam IDs isnt it :P

Comment: There have now been 15 responders. I'm still awaiting contact from a few of them.

If you still have interest, feel free to reply, although I cannot guarantee you a key. Regardless, everyone that receive one also received three guest passes and I hear that the game is going on sale on Steam soon (, as in, next week)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nice... here's my profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/kromak

I already joined the group ;)

Answer (score 0):

Joined the group, and here's my profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/RESPAWN_76

Answer (score 0):

Joined. My Profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/mactiddy/

Answer (score 0):

I'm in.

[fdisk7mbr](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197978062518)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in http://steamcommunity.com/id/blem

Answer (score 0):

I'm in! Here's my profile: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964085566

Comment: Any idea why other users have names as profile IDs and a few of us have numbers?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself. Maybe it's because I've been on Steam since the olden days of Half-life 2. Actually, it was a few months before that came out. January 24, 2004, baby. Oh yeah.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61174/what-does-my-profile-consist-of-numbers-instead-of-my-username) may illuminate the answer.

Comment: Cool. I don't really need my ID to be my name, I can copy and paste that just as easily as the numbers, but it is neat that you can change it

Answer (score 0):

[Sign me up!](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198047581965)

I have one question though: what happens if for some reason, someone is unable to run the game?

Comment: Review [the system requirements](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17710/)?

Comment: @MatthewRead: He means because he's running Ubuntu and does magic to run Steam.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Ahh, I see!

Comment: (We talked about this some in chat, but for reference) - Everyone appears to be getting 3 guest passes, so if you'd like to try it out beforehand, ask around and see if you can score one :)

Comment: @John I've got a guest pass you can have if you'd like to experiment.  Message me on steam later tonight and I'll send it to you

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Ullallulloo already sent me one.  Thanks for the offer, though!  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Count me in!](http://steamcommunity.com/id/fredley)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like NS, I'm game.

- https://steamcommunity.com/id/timko/

Answer (score 0):

Joined the group, [I'm me!](http://steamcommunity.com/id/thepugs)

Answer (score 0):

[What's not to love about free games](http://steamcommunity.com/id/xMrSmooth) and free rep (because I wouldn't be able to ask/answer questions about nuclear dawn without this giveaway).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds great, I'm game!  http://steamcommunity.com/id/jmacflex

Answer (score 0):

SURE! I will accompany my fellow gaming.SE'ers on this nuclear adventure!

http://steamcommunity.com/id/lesspopmorefizz/groups

Answer (score 0):

http://steamcommunity.com/id/Aceofgods/

I'll play. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm always down to try new stuff! http://steamcommunity.com/id/nihilistronin

Answer (score 0):

I need to check the meta more. This game looks really cool. Fingers crossed for number 16.

I am
 - http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197987075371